# Load XML Data into Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm still a newbie to rails. This is going to sound dart. I am implementing the JQuery UI autocomplete widget from [JQuery UI Autocomplete - XML](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#xml). I would like to know where and how do I store the XML file.

Comment: You mean you have a static XML file and need to send it from rails to the jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the example from the link you posted, it's getting the xml file from the server "london.xml" which is returning xml with fields "name", "countryname" and "geonameId".  If you are using rails create a route:

match '/london' => "locations#london" or something (not a very restful or good idea btw), and have the london action return the xml